# AngularJS and Jasmine testing factory

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, spyon

I am new to angularjs unit testing. I have a factory I am trying to spy on with jasmine and I can't figure out the syntax for the test spec. Below is the factory:

```
app.factory('assetFactory', function ($http) {
    var baseAddress = "../api/";
    var url = "";
    var factory = {};

    factory.getAssets = function (term) {
        url = baseAddress + "asset/search/" + term;
        return $http.get(url);
    };
    return factory;
});
```

Here is my test spec, which fails on the expect statement (Error: Expected spy getAssets to have been called):

```
describe('assetFactory', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        module('fixedAssetApp');
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function (assetFactory) {
        spyOn(assetFactory, 'getAssets').and.callThrough();
    }));

    it('should be defined', inject(function (assetFactory) {
        expect(assetFactory).toBeDefined();
    }));

    it('should have been called, inject(function (assetFactory) {
        expect(assetFactory.getAssets).toHaveBeenCalled();

    }));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add this change.

```
beforeEach(inject(function (assetFactory) {
        spyOn(assetFactory, 'getAssets').and.callThrough();
        assetFactory.getAssets();
    }));
```

In order to `toHaveBeenCalled()` return true, you must called your function either in `beforeEach` or `it` block.